# BeautifulSoup Python Selenium - Wait for tweet to load before scraping website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website to extract tweet links (Specifically DW in this case) but I am unable to get any data because the tweets are not loading immediately so the request executes before there is time to give it to load. I have tried using requests timeout as well as time.sleep() but without luck. After using those two options I tried using Selenium to load the webpage locally and give it time to load, but I can't seem to make it work. I believe this can be done with Selenium. Here is what I tried so far:

```
        links = 'https://www.dw.com/en/vaccines-appear-effective-against-india-covid-variant/a-57344037'
        driver.get(links)
        delay = 30 #seconds
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "twitter-widget-0")))
        except:
            pass
        tweetSource = driver.page_source
        tweetSoup = BeautifulSoup(tweetSource, features='html.parser')
        linkTweets = tweetSoup.find_all('a')
        for linkTweet in linkTweets:
            try:
                tweetURL = linkTweet.attrs['href']
            except:  # pass on KeyError or any other error
                pass
            if "twitter.com" in tweetURL and "status" in tweetURL:
                # Run getTweetID function
                tweetID = getTweetID(tweetURL)
                newdata = [tweetID, date_tag, "DW", links, title_tag, "News", ""]
                # Write to dataframe
                df.loc[len(df)] = newdata
                print("working on tweetID: " + str(tweetID))
```

If anyone could get Selenium to find the tweet that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an `iframe` first you need to switch to that iframe

```py
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "twitter-widget-0"))
    )
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it wait no matter if "twitter-widget-0" is there or not? Because some tweets still slip by for some reason so I would like every website to wait 15 seconds.

Comment: you simply can add `time.sleep`